# How can I see what proportion of rows in a table have a certain element

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
     region          LINE   
chr1-810865-3198369  L1MC4a  
chr1-810865-3198369  L1E33  
chr1-810865-3198369  L1MB5  
chr1-810865-3198369  L1MEc  
chr1-810865-3198369  L2a  
chr1-810865-3198369  L1M5  
chr2-100655-1344334  L1M5  
chr2-100655-1344334  L1E33  
etc.
```

I would like to see how many of the UNIQUE regions specified in $start to $end have each of the LINE in $LINE. I am trying to get an output like:

```
%OfAllRegions   LINE

 75%            L1M5
 53%            L1E33 etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't very clear as you have many additional variables in the provided data set which seem unrelated, but it seems like you are looking for the following

```
library(data.table)
(Res <- setDT(df)[, as.list(round(prop.table(table(LINE)) * 100)), .(start, end)])
#     start     end L1E33 L1M5 L1MB5 L1MC4a L1MEc L2a
# 1: 810865 3198369    17   17    17     17    17  17
# 2: 100655 1344334    50   50     0      0     0   0
```

If you want to added percent, you could simply do the following

```
Res[, names(Res)[-(1:2)] := lapply(.SD, paste0, "%"), .SDcols = -c("start", "end")][]
#     start     end L1E33 L1M5 L1MB5 L1MC4a L1MEc L2a
# 1: 810865 3198369   17%  17%   17%    17%   17% 17%
# 2: 100655 1344334   50%  50%    0%     0%    0%  0%
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(chr = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("chr1", "chr2"), class = "factor"), start = c(810865L, 
810865L, 810865L, 810865L, 810865L, 810865L, 100655L, 100655L
), end = c(3198369L, 3198369L, 3198369L, 3198369L, 3198369L, 
3198369L, 1344334L, 1344334L), chr2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "chr1", class = "factor"), start2 = c(814631L, 
818064L, 840645L, 849835L, 892914L, 918475L, 106773L, 107999L
), end2 = c(823247L, 822563L, 841179L, 850777L, 894175L, 919243L, 
107889L, 109923L), LINE = structure(c(4L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("L1E33", "L1M5", "L1MB5", "L1MC4a", "L1MEc", 
"L2a"), class = "factor"), d = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L)), .Names = c("chr", "start", "end", "chr2", "start2", "end2", 
"LINE", "d"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: @akrun added. the data

Comment: Thanks, I think the reason was because the columns I used were `character` instead of factor

Comment: Another option without using `prop.table` ie. `dt1 <- setDT(df)[, N:=uniqueN(LINE), .(start, end)][, paste0(round((.N/N)*100), '%') , .(start, end, LINE) ];  dcast.data.table(dt1, ...~LINE, value.var='V1', fill='0%')[order(-start,-end)]`

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. What Im really trying to do is see how many of all of the regions have each LINE. I think the solution provided gives me an idea of how many of each LINE makes up an individual region so I can say for example, that L1MC4a is found in 14% of all the regions, and L1E33 is found in 22% etc.